# How to fix this error: "E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead"?

Tags: apt

When I try to run the following command in Ubuntu 13.04:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I got following error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu- 
     com/xampp/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones  used
     instead
```

Comment: Did you add a ppa(http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) recently?

Comment: If yes, remove the ppa(http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) and try this again.

Comment: i try above all command but i failed to fix this